# SQL select ... in (select...) taking long time

Tags: mysql, sql, where-in

I have a table of items that users have bought, within that table there is a category identifier. So, I want to show users other items from the same table, with the same categories they have already bought from.

The query I'm trying is taking over 22 seconds to run and the main items table is not even 3000 lines... Why so inefficient? Should I index, if so which columns?

Here's the query:

```
select * from items
    where category in (
        select category from items 
        where ((user_id = '63') AND (category <> '0')) 
        group by category
    ) 
order by dateadded desc limit 20
```

Comment: Yes, you should index any and all columns that you will be using as an identifier in your queries. In this example you want to index `category`, and `dateadded`, and if not already a PK/index: `user_id`.

Comment: @BenAshton Thanks, will try that - already PK on user_id as you point out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a query. And sure add index on `category`,`user_id`,`dateadded`

```
select i1.* 
from items i1
inner join 
(select distinct 
           category 
        from items 
        where ((user_id = '63') AND (category <> '0'))
) i2 on (i1.Category=i2.Category)


order by i1.dateadded desc limit 20
```

Comment: From 22 seconds to 0.156 seconds - outstanding, thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Try using self join for better performance as:

```
 select i1.* from items i1 JOIN items i2 on i1.category= i2.category
 where i2.user_id = '63' AND i2.category <> '0'
 group by i2.category
 order by i1.dateadded desc limit 20
```

Join is much faster than nested subqueries.

**EDIT:** Try without `group by` as :

```
 select i1.* from items i1 JOIN items i2 on i1.category= i2.category
 where i2.user_id = '63' AND i2.category <> '0'
 order by i1.dateadded desc limit 20
```

Comment: This is not correct - it is only returning one item per category - therefore the user has bought from 18 categories, this only shows 18 results, one for each category

Comment: @DarrenSweeney: In that case, try after removing the `group by`.

Answer (score 1):

Appropriate places to put an index if necessary would be on `dateadded`, `user_id` and/or `category`

Comment: No because that would show only items the user already has - I want to see all items from the table whether they have them or not as the question says - other items

Comment: I think you are missing the group by line

Comment: @DarrenSweeney yes, you're right, I mis-read and have now re-read it. I have edited it now.  I think "YogendraSingh" has a good answer

Comment: @DerekOrgan I missed a whole lot more than then group-by line!

Answer (score 0):

If you index on `category` and possibly `dateadded`, it should speed things up a bit.